# Find a closed formula for the number of regions in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Suppose that the complete graph $K_n$ with $n$ vertices is drawn in the plane so that the vertices of $K_n$ form a convex $n$-gon, each edge is a straight line, and no three edges cross at a point. Let $f(n)$ be the number of regions that this drawing divides the plane into. For example, the following picture shows that $f(4)=5$, as the drawing divides the plane into five regions:

[image: image here]

Find, with proof, a closed-form formula for $f(n)$.

I turned this into a planar graph and found that the closed for for the number of vertices of the planar graph is $n + \binom n4$. But I'm not sure how to find the number of edges and how to continue after that. Any answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $G$ be the planar graph in this drawing. As you've found, it has $n + \binom n4$ vertices. It has the original vertices of $K_n$; beyond that, for any four vertices $a,b,c,d$ of $K_n$, exactly one of the intersections $ab \cap cd$, $ac \cap bd$, or $ad \cap bc$ exists (and is a vertex of $G$).

We can also figure out the number of edges of $G$. Each of the first $n$ vertices has degree $n-1$; each of the other $\binom n4$ vertices has degree $4$. Add up the degrees, and you get twice the number of edges.

Finally, Euler's formula $v - e + f = 2$ will tell us the number of faces of $G$ once we know the number of vertices and edges.